# Very strange jQuery / AJAX behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, alert

I have an Ajax call to the server that only works when I pass an `alert();` to it. Cannot figure out what is wrong. Can anyone help?

OBJECTIVE

1. If "Update" button clicked in PrettyPhoto iFrame - then (a) call server to run PHP script that updates backend database, (b) close PrettyPhoto window, and (c) refresh page
2. If "Don't Update" button clicked in PrettyPhoto iFrame - just (a) close PrettyPhoto window, and (b) refresh page

**This Does Not Work (ie., Ajax call to server does not get made):**

```
jQuery.support.cors = true; // needed for ajax to work in certain older browsers and versions

$('input[name="status"]').on("change", function() {

    if ($('input:radio[name="status"]:checked').val() == 'Y') {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://mydomain.com/dir/myPHPscript.php?param=' + $('#param').val() + '&id=' + ( $('#id').val() * 1 ) + '&mode=' + $('#mode').val()
        });

    }

    window.parent.closePP();

    window.top.location.href = $('#redirect').val();    // reloads page

});
```

**This Works! (ie., Ajax call to server gets made when I have the alert() present):**

```
jQuery.support.cors = true; // needed for ajax to work in certain older browsers and versions

$('input[name="status"]').on("change", function() {

    if ($('input:radio[name="status"]:checked').val() == 'Y') {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://mydomain.com/dir/myPHPscript.php?param=' + $('#param').val() + '&id=' + ( $('#id').val() * 1 ) + '&mode=' + $('#mode').val()
        });

        alert('this makes it work');

    }

    window.parent.closePP();

    window.top.location.href = $('#redirect').val();    // reloads page

});
```

Thanks.

**Made numerous revisions based on answers -- still can't get it to work. Here's latest:**

```
jQuery.support.cors = true; // needed for ajax to work in certain older browsers and versions

$('input[name="status"]').on("change", function() {

if ($('input:radio[name="status"]:checked').val() == 'Y') {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://mydomain.com/dir/myPHPscript.php?param=' + $('#param').val() + '&id=' + ( $('#id').val() * 1 ) + '&mode=' + $('#mode').val(),
        success: functions(data) {var $doNothing = data;}
    });

}

window.parent.closePP();
window.top.location.href = $('#redirect').val();    // reloads page

});
```

Comment: The latest will not work. You must move the close and location change into the success

Comment: I did (@mplungjan) and it did not close nor redirect. But the backend database got updated by the ajax call...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the rest in the Ajax callback

See [jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
$('input[name="status"]').on("change", function() {
    if ($('input:radio[name="status"]:checked').val() == 'Y') {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://mydomain.com/dir/myPHPscript.php?param=' + $('#param').val() + '&id=' + ( $('#id').val() * 1 ) + '&mode=' + $('#mode').val()
        },
        success:function() {
          window.parent.closePP();
          window.top.location.href = $('#redirect').val();    // reloads page
        });
     }
     else {
          window.parent.closePP();
     }
 });
```

You can also just get the data:

```
$('input[name="status"]').on("change", function() {
    if ($('input:radio[name="status"]:checked').val() == 'Y') {
        $.get('http://mydomain.com/dir/myPHPscript.php?param=' + $('#param').val() + '&id=' + ( $('#id').val() * 1 ) + '&mode=' + $('#mode').val(), 
         function() {
          window.parent.closePP();
          window.top.location.href = $('#redirect').val();    // reloads page
        });
     }
     else {
          window.parent.closePP();
     }
 });
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean @mplungjan

Comment: Ah, I see @mplungjan. Thanks for the revised script.  Appreciate it!!

Comment: What is the difference between the .ajax() and the .get() @mplungjan? All I need to do is evoke the server-side php script. Is one method better over the other in my particular case?

Comment: I tried your answer @mplungjan...could not get it to work I kept revising it to try to get the success to close() and redirect. But it only closes and redirects whet status == 'N'

Comment: $.get is much simpler than $.ajax. That is all. If you do not need all the error handling and such, $.get is just fine

Comment: You CANNOT do anything in the function after the ajax. you MUST do the rest in the success if using $.ajax or in the callback ,function()  if using $.get - I am off to bed. Sorry

Comment: Man this is frustrating@mplungjan. I tried .get(). The frame closes and the redirect works but my server-side script did not update the backend database.

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan. It's a private app behind a firewall. Odd thing is that I used the .ajax()  coding identically in another app I had without any success:, etc. and it worked in that app. The only difference is that I did not have any other javascript commands afterwards in my newer script where I did in my older script. I p[played with this thing for about 4 hours yesterday trying every combination I could think of. So I ended up putting a little alert() in there just to get it to work. It's annoying and not a streamlined solution, but a least it works

Comment: added an else I missed the first time... I need to see the html to be able to help you further...

Answer (score 2):

AJAX is asynchronous. The `$.ajax()` call will initiate a request to the server, and then the rest of your script will keep executing, even while the request is in-flight back to the server.

The alert() serves to 'slow down'/pause the rest of your code, allowing the ajax request to complete.

What you need to do is this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '....';
    success: someFunction;
});
```

when the ajax call succeeds, it will call `someFunction()`, which is where you'd do your .location.href stuff.

Comment: The jQuery is evkked `onChange` from a form. So if the val for status == 'N' the script falls through and the close and redirect work. If status = 'Y', the script works except for the ajax call. ( thanks@MarcB)

Comment: I simply want to launch the ajax call when status == 'Y' and then do the close() and redirect().

Comment: I tried your answer @MarcB...could not get it to work I kept revising it to try to get the success to close() and redirect. But it only closes and redirects whet status == 'N'

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$('input[name="status"]').on("change", function() {

    if ($('input:radio[name="status"]:checked').val() == 'Y') {

       $.ajax({
          url: '....',
          success: function(data) {
                    window.parent.closePP();
                    window.top.location.href = $('#redirect').val();  
                   }
       });      

    }
    else{

       window.parent.closePP();

       window.top.location.href = $('#redirect').val();    // reloads page
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried your answer @Chasee...could not get it to work I kept revising it to try to get the success to close() and redirect. But it only closes and redirects whet status == 'N'

Comment: Dot: I guess the script is correct but I have used a (;) instead of (,) with url initialization. Please fix it and try again.

Comment: I actually did use the comma @Charsee. Thanks.

Comment: are u returning some response from the server against this ajax call

Comment: No @Charsee -- it is not necessary. I simply use the ajax call to kickoff a server-side php script that updates a backend database. That's all it does.

Comment: Dot I guess this success thing will work when ajax call is complete and we get response back from the server. Until then there is no other way to make out that the ajax call is complete. Simply return anything from your server side.